# How to get GCP Logs to show up in CloudRun?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-logging

I see instructions at https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/logging to start logging, but I can't seem to see the logs in `https://console.cloud.google.com/run/detail/<location>/<service>/logs?project=<project>` for CloudRun, and I'm not sure where they are (I invoked them with `quickstart('my-project', 'my-log')`.

Answer (score 0):

To find logs the logs from the tutorial, use the logs explorer `https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/query` with the query `logName="projects/<project>/logs/<log_name>"`, so in your case, `logName="projects/my-project/logs/my-log"` of when you're editing the query you can find it in the dropdown under `log name`.

To log to `CloudRun` you need to set the following in the meta data:

```
{
   ...,
   resource: { 
      type: 'cloud_run_revision', 
      labels: { service_name: 'my-service', location: 'us-east1' } },
}
```

You can use this sample function to test:

```js
const log = async (text, name) => {
   const gcpLogger = new Logging({ projectId: 'smodin-dev' })

   const logSet = gcpLogger.log(name)
   const metadata = {
      severity: 'INFO',
      resource: { 
         type: 'cloud_run_revision', 
         labels: { service_name: 'my-service', location: 'us-east1' } 
      },
   }
   const entry = logSet.entry(metadata, text)
   await logSet.write(entry)
}
```

PS: If there is a different recommended method I'm all ears